How to fix the NUCLEO F722ZE Board clock error
I removed the STlink of the NUCLEO F722ZE board and wrote it, but there was a clock error, so the program itself is not working
It worked normally when there was Stlink, but it's not working
I set it to HSI and used it, but it didn't work, so a clock issue occurred to switch to HSE, so I thought it would be okay to just debug it, but at some point, the clock didn't work, so it didn't come out of stop mode
I set it as an rtc alarm and woke it up, but it seems like a clock error when it stops after going well
How can I fix this error?
Stlink uses a lot of electric current, so it needs to be removed
I removed only the stlink from the hardware, but this is the situation
Original settings before removing STlink

Setting changed to clock error after removing STlink

This is the setting I used before, but after removing the STlink, the HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStructure) error handle occurred in this part
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 216;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

It's a code related to stop mode
void RTC_Init(void)
{
    __HAL_RCC_RTC_ENABLE();

    hrtc.Instance = RTC;
    hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
    hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
    hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
    hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
    hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
    HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc);

    // Get current time
    RTC_TimeTypeDef currentTime;
    HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &currentTime, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);

    // Calculate alarm time (current time + 50 seconds)
    RTC_AlarmTypeDef sAlarm;
    sAlarm.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime = currentTime;
    sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds += 30;

    // Handle overflow of seconds
    if (sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds >= 60)


    {
        sAlarm.AlarmTime.Seconds -= 60;
        sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes++;
        if (sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes >= 60)
        {
            sAlarm.AlarmTime.Minutes -= 60;
            sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours++;
            if (sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours >= 24)
            {
                sAlarm.AlarmTime.Hours -= 24;
            }
        }
    }

    sAlarm.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
    sAlarm.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
    sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_DATE;
    sAlarm.AlarmDateWeekDay = 0;

    HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &sAlarm, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
}

void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)
{
    // Handle the alarm event
    // Wake up the system or perform necessary actions here
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);  // Clear wake-up flag if necessary
}


void vStopMode(void)
{

    /* Suspend SysTick */
    HAL_SuspendTick();

    /* Enable Power Peripheral */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* Initialize RTC and set alarm */
    RTC_Init();

    /* STOP Mode */
    //HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);

    /* Resume SysTick When System Wake-up */
    HAL_ResumeTick();

    /* PLL Clock Recovery */
    SystemClock_Config();

    // 전력 안정화를 위해 잠시 대기
    HAL_Delay(100);  // 100ms 정도 대기


}


Your description of the problem is unclear. What exactly did you do, what exactly did you switch? From what clock exactly do you want it to run? At what frequency? Are you sure you need HSE Bypass? Normally you don't need HSE bypass with an external xtal.
